# copy.to send data, but it's a different Google Drive email

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script, google-sheets

I'm very new to Javascript and Apps Script I'm looking to create a function that updates another sheet based on the date in a specific range of the active sheet. I run and there are no errors but it is not transferring the values from the active sheet to the named sheet "January".

Please help me see what I'm not seeing.

```
function myFunction2() {
const spreadsheetIds = ["https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FpZZJrYrVqHLSCp3i5vY0qGWPOFD7lsUKu1DIa52C18/edit#gid=0"];// Please set your spreadshet IDs.

const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("January");
if (!srcSheet) return;
const values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues();
if (values.filter(r => r.join("")).length == 0) return;
for (let i = 0; i < spreadsheetIds.length; i++) {
const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i]);
const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cab5");
if (targetSheet) {
targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 3, values.length, 
values[0].length).setValues(values);
}
}
}
```

[Master data](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1MBc8wm_6u_zGAGljMp4A1dFzBzgEwH0dLsum6GjYCaU/edit#gid=0)

[output 1 user 2](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1FpZZJrYrVqHLSCp3i5vY0qGWPOFD7lsUKu1DIa52C18/edit#gid=0)

I want to send data, but it's a different Google Drive email

Master data  gmail@gmail.com
send data to
output 1 user 2  yahoo@gmail.com

Comment: I cannot see "Master data". Can you confirm it, again? And, about `Master data gmail@gmail.com send data to output 1 user 2 yahoo@gmail.com`, if you want to put the value to the Spreadsheet of another user account, it is required to share the Spreadsheet with your account. Please be careful about this. Do you have permission for putting the values on the destination Spreadsheet? By the way, in your script, `spreadsheetIds` has the URL. By this, I think that an error occurs at `SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i]);`. Please be careful about this.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

#### Modification points:

- In your script, `spreadsheetIds` has the URL. By this, I think that an error occurs at `SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i]);`. But, you say `I run and there are no errors`. So, I'm worried that you might have miscopied your script.
- From `transferring the values from the active sheet to the named sheet "January"`, in this case, I think that `const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("January");` is `const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet();`. And, `const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cab5");` is `const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("January");`.
- About `copy.to send data, but it's a different Google Drive email`, in this case, please confirm that you have permission for putting the values to the Spreadsheet of another user account. If you don't have it, an error occurs at `const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i]);`. Please be careful about this. **Before you test the script, please confirm whether the destination Spreadsheet has already been shared with your account as the writer.**

When these points are reflected in your script, it becomes as follows.

#### Modified script:

```js
function myFunction2() {
  const spreadsheetIds = ["1FpZZJrYrVqHLSCp3i5vY0qGWPOFD7lsUKu1DIa52C18"]; // Modified

  const srcSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();
  const srcSheet = srcSpreadsheet.getActiveSheet(); // Modified
  if (!srcSheet) return;
  const values = srcSheet.getRange("A2:D32").getValues();
  if (values.filter(r => r.join("")).length == 0) return;
  for (let i = 0; i < spreadsheetIds.length; i++) {
    const dstSpreadsheet = SpreadsheetApp.openById(spreadsheetIds[i]);
    const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("January"); // Modified
    if (targetSheet) {
      targetSheet.getRange(targetSheet.getLastRow() + 1, 3, values.length,
        values[0].length).setValues(values);
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: Tanaike , thanks answer. the file has been shared, with edit access output 1 user 2 to Master data. and I've used the script but it doesn't send data to script Modified script:. maybe const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cab5");

Comment: @dra Thank you for replying. About `but it doesn't send data to script Modified script:. maybe const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cab5");`, I apologize for the inconvenience. But, unfortunately, my proposed modified script doesn't use `const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("Cab5");`. In my answer, from your question of `transferring the values from the active sheet to the named sheet "January".`, I modified it to `const targetSheet = dstSpreadsheet.getSheetByName("January");`. So, I'm worried that you might not use my proposed modified script. How about this?

Comment: Tanaike,thank you for answering my question for the umpteenth time. thanks for the lesson. im changing january to cab5

Comment: @dra Thank you for replying. From your reply, I understand` im changing january to cab5`.

Comment: if, code error :Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: https://www.googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets
myFunction3 @ sendto.gs:10

Comment: @dra About About `if, code error :Exception: You do not have permission to call SpreadsheetApp.openById. Required permissions: googleapis.com/auth/spreadsheets myFunction3 @ sendto.gs:10 `, I have already mentioned permission for putting values to the Spreadsheet in my comment and answer. So, please confirm the permission again.

Comment: ok share all files. to read each other's files. ok ok . thanks – Tanaike